# VBS script to run a batch file, not running at start-up

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-10

I have run it by click and run as Admin and it works normally.

When I put it in a shortcut, configured to run as Admin, it wont launch at startup.

This is my VBS script:

```
Set objshell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
objshell.run("C:\ERPSystem\znc\backup\bat\callbackupdb.bat"),0, true
```

I imagine that it has something with the permissions in the OS, because it works normaly in other computers.

Comment: How do you know? It is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

If it works normally in other computer then problem is in your os u can try by placing the file in the same directory or by running the script as administrator i have tried your script it runs fine in my laptop ( just changed batch file )

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim PathApplication,ShortcutName,VbsPath
VbsPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
PathApplication = "C:\ERPSystem\znc\backup\bat\callbackupdb.bat"
ShortcutName = "Backupdb"
Call Shortcut(VbsPath,ShortcutName)
Call Hidden_Run(Dblquote(PathApplication))
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Shortcut(PathApplication,ShortcutName)
    Dim objShell,StartFolder,objShortCut,MyTab
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyTab = Split(PathApplication,"\")
    If ShortcutName = "" Then
        ShortcutName = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    StartFolder = objShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(StartFolder & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(PathApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,-25"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Hidden_Run(MyProgram)
    Dim ws,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Result = ws.run(MyProgram,0,True) '0 to hide the program
    Hidden_Run = Result
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```